# Simple switch statement error?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Let me know if you guys see anything wrong with this.  I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at interaction.menu(interaction.java:15)
    at driver.main(driver.java:9)
```

Line 15 is `selection = scan.nextInt();` right inside the while loop.  The main simply contains a method that calls this method in this class.

```
//provides the interface to be used
    public void menu(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    database db = new database();
    int selection;

    while(true){
        hugeTextBlock();
        selection = scan.nextInt();
        switch(selection){
            //creates a new course
            case 1: db.addCourse();
            //removes a course
            case 2: db.deleteCourse();
            //enroll a student
            case 3: db.enrollStudent();
            //delete a student
            case 4: db.deleteStudent();
            //register for a course
            case 5: db.registerStudent();
            //drop a course
            case 6: db.dropCourse();
            //check student registration
            case 7: db.checkReg();
            //quit
            case 8: break;  
            default: System.out.println("default action");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the addCourse method inside another class.  I have ran it by itself and it works just fine.

```
//creates a new course
public void addCourse(){
    try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StudentRegistration_DSN");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the course title: ");
    String title = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the course's code: ");
    String code = scan.next();

    st.executeUpdate("insert into course values('"+code+"','"+title+"')");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from course");
    code = "";
    title = "";
    System.out.println("This is the relation as of current changes.");

    while (rs.next())
    {
       code=rs.getString(1);
       title=rs.getString(2);
       System.out.println("Code: " + code + "   Title: " + title);
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    conn.close();
    scan.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably should have some break in your switch...

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html. (In particular, search that page for the phrase *fall through*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling that `Scanner.nextInt` has no int to read. You should ensure that the next thing scanner will return is, in fact, an int. See [Scanner.hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).

```
while (!scanner.hasNext()) {
    // sleep here
}
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   selection = scan.nextInt();
} else {
    selection = 0;
    scan.next();  // reads the garbage.
}
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but it doesn't stop for me to input another integer.  It just finishes the method and crashes.  I thought that the case would finish and the while loop would start everything back over again like it did the first time.  Should I do a statement checking `if (scan.hasNextInt)` and if it doesn't, do another scan?

Comment: Edit: the switch statement works fine if I use another case.  The while loop just keeps it going.  Also, `db.addCourse();` works outside the switch statement.  What happens when the method finishes that messes up the scanner object?

Comment: The exception will stop the current thread. It won't run anymore. You'll need to check if there's input and if the input is an integer. And read accordingly. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Okay, it seems that after it completes the first chosen case, it goes back through the while loop and gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, only breaking the switch on case 8 will cause weird things to happen. You should add a break after every case, and add `System.exit(0)` for case 8.

Second, did you type anything at the scanner prompt? If you type an end-of-input symbol, this will happen. Also, what stream does `System.in` correspond to? If you are invoking this from a genuine command line and do not type the end-of-input, I don't see how this could happen.

Comment: I am just using the console inside Eclipse.  I went through and added breaks and your exit command.  Did I type anything at the scanner prompt? The first time, it does whatever I want it to.  Then after it completes that task, it goes back through the original while loop and crashes without asking me for another input.